# Jsonp Help printing each item from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, yahoo

I posted a question earlier in regards to yahoo's Auction Api with jsonp

Here is a snippet of the array.

```js
"Result": {
      "UnitsWord": [
        "example1",
        "example2",
        "example3",
        "example4",
        "example5"
      ]
},
```

Here is my code

```js
function changeText2(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    $jsonurl = "https://auctions.yahooapis.jp/AuctionWebService/V2/json/search?appid="instert-yahooidhere"-&query=" + userInput;
 
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: ($jsonurl),
  contentType: 'application/json',
  dataType:'jsonp',
  responseType:'application/json',
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  },
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : true,
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'application/json',
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
   $.each(data, function (i, test) {
 $('#howmany').append('<p><b>' + test["Result"]["UnitsWord"] + '</b> Was Found</p>');
    });
  },
  error: function(error) {
  
    console.log("Failed");
  }
});
}
```

What im trying to do
Is wrap

```html
<div id="howmany">
<p><b>example1</b> products found</p>
<p><b>example2</b> products found</p>
<p><b>example3</b> products found</p>
<p><b>example4</b> products found</p>
<p><b>example5</b> products found</p>
</div>
```

If im doing something wrong,
Please let me know.
Or at least direct me to where i can find some more information on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `Result` is a property of your `data` and `UnitsWord` is a property of `Result` which holds an array. So to iterate over that array, you need:

```
$.each(data.Result.UnitsWord)
```

In other words, `data.Result.UnitsWord` is the array you want to loop ever with each. This will give you one of the `example_x` strings for each iteration.

```js
let data= {
   "Result": {
      "UnitsWord": [
        "example1",
        "example2",
        "example3",
        "example4",
        "example5"
      ]
    }
  }


$.each(data.Result.UnitsWord, function (i, test) {
 $('#howmany').append('<p><b>' + test + '</b> Was Found</p>');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="howmany">
```